# List comprehension with early conditional check

Tags: python, list-comprehension

For the given list `l`

```
l = [{'k': [1, 2]}, {'k': [2, 8]}, {'k': [6, 32]}, {}, {'s': 0}]
```

where I would like to have a single list of all values

```
r = [1, 2, 2, 8, 6, 32]
```

and the code

```
r = []
for item in l:
    if 'k' in item:
        for i in item['k']:
            r += [i]
```

is there an elegant list comprehension solution for this kind of list?

Obviously,

```
[i for i in item['k'] if 'k' in item for item in l]
```

fails, because `item['k']` is accessed before the condition is checked. Any ideas?

Comment: can the dictionaries have keys other than `"k"` or is it always one of 1 key or empty dict?

Comment: Yes, can have other keys as well. I updated the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `get` to provide an empty list to iterate over if `k` doesn't exist.

```
r = [i for d in l for i in d.get('k', [])]
```

Or, check for `k` before you try to access its value.

```
r = [i for d in l if 'k' in d for i in d['k']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost have the right solution with your list comprehension. It is just that the order of statements inside list comprehension is wrong. Please try the following.

```py
l = [{'k': [1, 2]}, {'k': [2, 8]}, {'k': [6, 32]}, {}, {'s': 0}]
answer = [i for item in l if 'k' in item for i in item['k'] ]
print(answer)
```

Is this what you wanted?